# Html background-size

Tags: html, css

I have background image size 1920x200. In my browser i have different scale, so the width of my image in browser is more than 1920. To see the entire  image i have to change the scale to 75%. But i am trying to make a size of my background image no bigger and no less than browser box with different scales. My code looks like

```
<nav class="navbar navbarlogo">
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-6">
        <h4> Sample text 1</h4>
        <h5> Sample text 2</h5>
    </div>
</div>
</nav>

.navbarlogo {
    height: 200px;
    background: url("../img/html-page-background-color-with-29-web-pics-s-at.png") no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
```

This code doesn't work exactly how i want. What's wrong?

Comment: Your requirements cause the background image to stretch, since the height needs to be 200px always and the width needs to be the width of the window, can that be right?

Comment: Could you provide your code on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about closing the navbar?

```
<nav class="navbar navbarlogo"></nav>
```

and use

```
background-size:contain;
```